# Conditionally insert a character when missing

Tags: excel, vba

I need to check a range of cells and if there is a missing `-` I will add it only if the cell starts with a `B`. Here is what I have tried: (example: `B0401234` should be `B04-01234`).

```
Sub FixText()
  For Each x In Range("A1:A39534")
    If InStr(x.Value, "-") = -1 Then
      If InStr(x.Value, "B") = 0 Then
        x.Value = Left(x.Value, 3) & "-" & Right(x.Value, 5)
      End If
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

After running the macro I see no changes.

Comment: string functions are **1** based: `instr("ABC", "Z") = 0` so it will never equal `-1`

Comment: I seem to forget that when doing VBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
Sub FixText()
  For Each x In Range("A1:A39534")
    If InStr(x.Value, 4) <> "-" And Left(x.Value, 1) = "B" Then
        x.Value = Left(x.Value, 3) & "-" & Right(x.Value, 5)
      End If
  Next
End Sub
```